# Array destructure with an OR operator issue, Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Return true from function foo and structure it with an OR operator.

```js
function foo() {
  return true;
}
var [a, b, c] = foo() || [];
```

Why it is throwing an error like foo is not a function.

Comment: `var [a, b, c] = foo() || [];` ==> `var [a, b, c] =  true;` ??

Comment: What's the *actual* error you're seeing? When I run your code, I get `TypeError: true is not iterable` which is the same problem Pranav was pointing out.

Comment: VM356:4 Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
    at <anonymous>:4:17

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Wanted to see a, b and c as an undefined

Comment: why do you need the function call and why logical OR?

Answer (score 2):

The actual error is in fact:
`TypeError: foo is not a function or its return value is not iterable`.

This is because the execution will not reach the OR statement because the result of `foo()` is not false-y (It is infact true). Hence, javascript tries to destructure `true`, which gives you a TypeError

Comment: That full error is shown only when  `|| []` is omitted (in chrome)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Worked fine on firefox for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in V8 error reporting:

```js
function foo() {
  return true;
} 


var [a] = foo() ; // Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function or its return value is not iterable
var [a] = foo() || []; // Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
```

Firefox correctly reports "is not iterable" in both cases.